# If I add a system that emits events to a stage following the `EVENT` stage, will that delay the reading of those events?

Tags: rust, bevy

I have a system (let's call it `game_event`) that consumes input events from various sources (keyboard, gamepad, etc) and maps them to game-specific events (move, jump, etc). My understanding is that if I add my `game_event` system to the `EVENT` stage, then it will run in parallel with the input system, delaying the reading of input events by a frame. The obvious solution would be to add the `game_event` system to the `PRE_UPDATE` stage, but it's unclear whether or not doing so is a good idea—I assume an `EVENT` stage exists for a reason.

If I add a system that emits events to a stage following the `EVENT` stage, will that delay the reading of those events by systems in subsequent stages?